# Relationship between conjugacy classes and their respective centralizers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on a problem from Artin which asks to rule out as many class equations for a group of order 10 as I can. I'm are unsure about one:

1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2

My thought was that there are four conjugacy classes of order 2 each, so their corresponding centralizers will each have order five. Since they have prime order, we know the centralizers are all cyclic, so that implies they're the same. But what kind of group would have four conjugacy classes with the same centralizer?

Comment: @DonAntonio Well that just means they are in the center, correct? And since there are 2, which divides 10, that's okay as far as I know.

Comment: Of course. I misunderstood.

Comment: Can you use Sylow theorems and etc.?

Comment: @DonAntonio These exercises come before the Sylow theorems are introduced, so I figured there was a way to figure it out without them. Up until now, I have the class equation and counting formula which are what I was working with.

Comment: Ayman just posted an excellent answer, which assumes you already know, or can prove, that for *any* group, its quotient over its center cannot be cyclic non-trivial

Comment: The proof of the theorem I use is quite elementary. It's very useful in this kind of situations.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Thank you, yes I am familiar with this, and wish I thought of it beforehand! But back to my original line of thinking, is there no immediate contradiction that comes from having several conjugacy classes with the same centralizer? Could you provide an example of where this is the case if not?

Comment: Well @user59699 : a rather trivial example for that is any abelian group...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio haha, of course - I guess I should have specified nontrivial!

Comment: Apart from abelian groups, I can't think of an example or proof at the moment. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\left|Z(G)\right| = 2$, then $|G/Z(G)| = 5$. Thus $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic. Hence $G$ is abelian by [this theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_of_Group_by_Center_Cyclic_implies_Abelian). This contradicts with $|Z(G)| = 2$. It follows that no group has the class equation you have.